# Is it possible to get alert if any instances is not running under security groups in EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Basically, If there are 3 instances running in one of my security group then if suddenly, out of 3, if one instance is not responding then I need to send cloudWatch Alert. Is it possible ? If not then any alternative solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Define "not running" - EC2 stopped, web server not responding ... How does security groups fit into your question? Please update your question to help us understand your problem.

Comment: Did you get my questions now?

Comment: Your problem description is vague. `Instances running in security group` What does it mean? `instance is not responding` - too general.

Comment: Yes, if instance status gets failed by any reason then I need to set cloudWatch alam. Important thing is that I need it at security group level not at instance level.

Comment: You are not understanding security groups. SGs are attached to network interfaces. SGs do not report status. You need to define what you want to monitor in your instances and then setup CloudWatch alarms based upon that criteria.

Comment: I would like to be able to set cloudwatch alerts that monitor how many instances of a certain security group are running, and if the # of instances for that security group that are running goes below a certain number, an alert should be sent out. This is the requirement. Is it possible through clouldWatch?

Comment: You won't be able to do that with an alert, you need to configure a Cloudwatch Scheduled Event that will execute a Lambda function which executes API calls to get your instances and count the instances with a specific security group.  The recurring of your event could be minimum 1 minute for every loop.

Comment: Could you please guide me more on this? Any reference code or python code you have?

Answer (score 1):

## This approach uses the following services

- [Cloudwatch Scheduled Event.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html)
- [AWS Lambda function.](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)

  - Create an [IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) with permissions to publish SNS messages and for logging through Cloudwatch logs.
- [Simple Notification Service (SNS).](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/)

### Create a [SNS topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/CreateTopic.html)

Create a SNS topic and subscribe the receivers for the future notifications from the Lambda function.  Let's called `MyTopic`.

### Create an [IAM Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) with the following policy

Let's call it `DummyRole` (the name for this role is up to you).
This role will be attached to the new Lambda Function to grant permission for publishing, logging and describing EC2 instances.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:450338205852:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:450338205852:log-group:/aws/lambda/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:450338205852:MyTopic"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Replace `accountId` with the current account.

### Create a new Lambda function

- The name of this new Lambda function is up to you, for this example, the name is `InstancesInSG`, and let's attach the IAM Role `DummyRole`.  The implementation of this Lambda function to get the instances with a security group and for sending emails is up to you.  In this example, I'm only logging the event from Cloudwatch.

**Lambda function NodeJs example**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

"use strict";

//These constants must be declared in Environment variables.
const THRESHOLD = 5; // Lesser than this will notify to SNS topic.
const SECURITY_GROUPS = ['sg-11111']; //Only EC2 instances with this security group.
const TOPIC_ARN = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:AccountId:MyTopic";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var settings = { apiVersion: '2017-01-01', region: process.env.AWS_REGION };
    var ec2 = new AWS.EC2(settings);
    var params = {
        DryRun: false,
        MaxResults: THRESHOLD, // This value must be equals to the THRESHOLD.  The min value is 5.
        Filters: []
    };
            
    // You can use 'instance.group-name' to filter by security group's name.
    params.Filters = [
        {
            Name: 'instance.group-id',
            Values: SECURITY_GROUPS
        }, 
        {
            Name: 'instance-state-code',
            Values: ['16']
        }
    ];
    
    ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            let count = 0;
            let reservations = data['Reservations'] || [];
            for (let i = 0; i < reservations.length; i++) {
                count += reservations[i]['Instances'].length;
            }
            
            if (count < THRESHOLD) {
                console.log("Sending SNS notification!");

                var sns = new AWS.SNS({region: process.env.AWS_REGION});
                let snsparams = { TargetArn: TOPIC_ARN, Message: `Only ${count} Instance(s) with security group '${SECURITY_GROUPS}' are running, please take action.`, Subject: 'EC2 Notification' };
                sns.publish(snsparams, callback);
                callback();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

**Lambda function Java example**

```
int THRESHOLD = 5; // Lesser than this will notify to SNS topic.
String[] SECURITY_GROUPS = new String[]{"sg-11111"}; //Only EC2 instances with this security group.
String TOPIC_ARN = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:AccountId:MyTopic";

AmazonEC2 ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.defaultClient();

DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
request.setMaxResults(THRESHOLD);
ArrayList<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
Filter filter = new Filter();
filter.setName("instance.group-id");
filter.setValues(Arrays.asList(SECURITY_GROUPS));

filter = new Filter();
filter.setName("instance-state-code");
filter.setValues(Collections.singletonList("16"));

request.setFilters(filters);
DescribeInstancesResult response = ec2.describeInstances(request);

int count = response.getReservations().stream().mapToInt(reservation -> reservation.getInstances().size()).sum();
if (count < THRESHOLD) {
    AmazonSNS sns = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    String msg = String.format("Only %d Instance(s) with security group '%s' are running, please take action.", count, Arrays.toString(SECURITY_GROUPS));
    PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(TOPIC_ARN, msg, "EC2 Notification");
    sns.publish(publishRequest);
}
```

**You can download the Java Maven project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d-TTES1WocKeHfvM8EwpWJx6l1gXxSua/view?usp=sharing)**.

**Notification message in my inbox:** *Only 2 Instance(s) with security group 'sg-09311111' are running, please take action.*

---

[image]

### Create Cloudwatch Scheduled Event

Here you need to pick a Scheduled Event Rule, set the recurring window to 1 min and pick the Target.  The target will be the Lambda Function `InstancesInSG`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**This is the event printed into the logs in Cloudwatch:**

[image]

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Thanks a lot Eleazar. May I know here how it get instances from security group and fulfill my requirement like how many instances of a certain security group are running, and if the # of instances for that security group that are running goes below a certain number, an alert should be sent out.

Comment: Do you need the code in Python?  I can share with you NodeJs code.

Comment: I need code in python. if not then share whatever you have and it would be good if you can explain me how it works as I'm new in AWS and not much aware about lambda function(how it works and creates in aws)

Comment: Got it, I'm going to put an example in NodeJs and I will add a little more about how to create Lambda function and how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro... Can you please confirm that by this way it fulfill my requirement?

Comment: Yes, it will.  Because the Lambda function will validate the count of instances with a specific security group.  If that count is below than a min threshold a notification will be sent to the SNS topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your profile said you're good in Java as well. If you've answer in Java then please share it to me so I can understand the same as my core skill is in Java. Thank you very much for all you help and efforts.

Comment: @JwalinShah I can do that, tomorrow I can share the code with you!!

Comment: looking for for your response.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help.Will be trying to execute the same and hope it works as expected. May I have your contact details? Gtalk or Skype?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163663/discussion-between-eleazar-enrique-and-jwalin-shah).

Comment: I'm there on chat an waiting for your respond.

Answer (score 0):

`I would like to be able to set cloudwatch alerts that monitor how many instances of a certain security group are running, and if the # of instances for that security group that are running goes below a certain number, an alert should be sent out.`

If possible, and this is the ideal case, I suggest creating autoscaling groups and then create CloudWatch alarms and maybe even autoscaling actions that automatically does what you want instead of having to have a human respond to the event.

If that doesn't work, yes, you can always just create CloudWatch alarms on the specific EC2 instances to watch for `StatusCheckFailed` or something similiar.

This has nothing to with security groups.

Comment: Simon, I've already that in places. But my requirement is different than what AWS in build supports.